# Creating multiple items with a single creation workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create multiple items (associated classes) from the parent class to the very child one (4 level deep) in a single workflow. I'd like to be able to create the parent item, then click on "next" to be able to create one/many children, then click on "next" to create the children of the children, and so on... Finally, in the last screen, i'd like to be able to save all the items by clicking on save. If something is missing in the child item, the parent class cannot be created as well.

Do we have any ideas of how i can manage to do that?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the parent model to associate the child models,.

In the view you can use `fields_for` or `simple_fields_for` (if simple_form  gem is used) to list the child model fields in the subsequent steps,.

In every step rather than saving the object in the db, you can check if the object is valid or not using `.valid?` instead of `save`. At the final step you can use .save `method`.

With .valid? you can get the errors at each step and at the final step you can save all the records by creating the parent object.